# CSS Animation duration variable wont update

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

Im making a heart rate animation with real data (BEATS PER MINUTE).

```css
transform: rotate(45deg);
animation: animateHeart 0s infinite;
```

**This is my animation:**

```css
@keyframes animateHeart {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.8);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.8);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

When I do something like this inside a method:

```js
const duration = (60 / BPM);
document.getElementById('heart').style.animationDuration = duration.toFixed(2) + 's';
```

It will only execute once.

Comment: Can you upload your whole code into jsfiddle?

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz something like this: https://codepen.io/ksycz/pen/MVvqpy. 
`animation: .8s infinite beatHeart;` needs to be a variable, .8s i mean

Comment: When you make `const duration = (60 / BPM);` to `const duration = 60;` or any value besides 60, problem resolves. Probably `BPM` is not defined as variable. Try to define BPM as a variable and assign a value to it.